# Is there a way to cap the file size of slony log shipping files?

Tags: slony

I am working with a SuSE machine (cat /etc/issue: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP1  (i586)) running Postgresql 8.1.3 and the Slony-I replication system (slon version 1.1.5).  We have a working replication setup going between two databases on this server, which is generating log shipping files to be sent to the remote machines we are tasked to maintain.  As of this morning, we ran into a problem with this.

For a while now, we've had strange memory problems on this machine - the oom-killer seems to be striking even when there is plenty of free memory left.  That has set the stage for our current issue to occur - we ran a massive update on our system last night, while replication was turned off.  Now, as things currently stand, we cannot replicate the changes out - slony is attempting to compile all the changes into a single massive log file, and after about half an hour or so of running, it trips over the oom-killer issue, which appears to restart the replication package.  Since it is constantly trying to rebuild that same package, it never gets anywhere.

My first question is this: Is there a way to cap the size of Slony log shipping files, so that it writes out no more than 'X' bytes (or K, or Meg, etc.) and after going over that size, closes the current log shipping file and starts a new one?  We've been able to hit about four megs in size before the oom-killer hits with fair regularity, so if I could cap it there, I could at least start generating the smaller files and hopefully eventually get through this.

My second question, I guess, is this: Does anyone have a better solution for this issue than the one I'm asking about?  It's quite possible I'm getting tunnel vision looking at the problem, and all I really need is -a- solution, not necessarily -my- solution.